# Simplification k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4 - 5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am interesting in express the following expresion as trigonometric expresion  as
$$Mod[k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4, 5]$$ using FUllSIMPLIFY you get
$$-5 \left\lfloor \frac{1}{5} \left(4 k^4+k^3+4 k^2+k\right)\right\rfloor +4 k^4+k^3+4 k^2+k$$
it it possible to get a trigonometric expresion or any equivalent expresion as combination of  $$\frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^k-1\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
f[k_] = Mod[k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4, 5];
g[k_] = 1/5 + (Sqrt[5] - 1)/10 Cos[(2 k π)/5] -
              (Sqrt[5] + 1)/10 Cos[(4 k π)/5] -
              Sqrt[(5 + Sqrt[5])/50] Sin[(2 k π)/5] -
              Sqrt[(5 - Sqrt[5])/50] Sin[(4 k π)/5];

Table[f[k] - g[k], {k, 0, 100}] // FullSimplify
(*    {0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0}    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

An extended comment follows in order to avoid writing to many comments under the OP.

In `Version 12` if I just do a `FullSimplify` in the first expression that you present -as you suggest- I get the following:

```
FullSimplify[Mod[k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4, 5]]
```

> `Mod[k (1 + 4 k) (1 + k^2), 5]`

Interestingly we can perform the following:

```
FunctionExpand[Mod[k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4, 5]]
```

> `k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4 - 5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)]`

We can, of course, test the following: first expression you give with the `Mod` minus the second one that involves the `Floor` function

```
FullSimplify[
 Mod[k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4, 
   5] - (-5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)] + k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 
    4 k^4)]
```

> `0`

Note that to get the equality `Factor` and `Simplify` are not sufficient.

Finally, we test -numerically- the final claim that is made; i.e to pass from the expression with the `Floor` to the expression with the `k`-power

```
Table[-5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)] + k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 
  4 k^4, {k, 0, 10}]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}`

On the other hand

```
Table[1/2 ((-1)^k - 1), {k, 0, 10}]
```

> `{0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0}`

Question: are you sure you wanted to write

$$
\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)^k -1\right)
$$

and not something else?

Edit: after the edit in the OP I can suggest the following line of work.

Alternative 1: $
\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)^k -1\right)
$ and `Sin[of something]`

If we check

```
Table[-(1/2) (1/2 ((-1)^k - 1) + Sin[Pi/2 k]), {k, 0, 15}]
Table[-5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)] + k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 
  4 k^4, {k, 0, 15}]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}`

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}`

we realize that the first pattern is 3 0's in a row and then a single 1, and the second pattern is 4 0's in a row and a single 1. Not sure if anyone else can come up with a single answer, but I could not. I thought it was a nice observation so I am leaving it here as a comment.

What I thought I could do -and worked- is to consider the difference of the above and from the result build a final formula. That is, we run:

```
Table[-5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)] + k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 
   4 k^4, {k, 0, 15}] - 
 Table[-(1/2) (1/2 ((-1)^k - 1) + Sin[Pi/2 k]), {k, 0, 15}]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1}`

and then come up with a function that compensates for the above.

```
expre1 = FindSequenceFunction[{0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 
        0, 0, 1, -1}, k] /. k -> k + 1 // Factor // Simplify // 
   Rationalize;
```

`FindSequenceFunction` gives a very ugly output and did not have the patience to wait for `FullSimplify`. A quick check that the above actually works

```
Chop[SetPrecision[
  Table[-5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)] + k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 
     4 k^4, {k, 0, 15}] - 
   Table[-(1/2) (1/2 ((-1)^k - 1) + Sin[Pi/2 k]) + expre1, {k, 0, 
     15}] , $MachinePrecision]]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Alternative 2: $
\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)^k -1\right)
$ and `Cos[of something]`

Well the strategy is the same as above, so I move through this one quickly.

Starting from

```
Table[-5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)] + k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 
   4 k^4, {k, 0, 15}] - 
 Table[(1/2 ((-1)^k - 1)) - (-1 + Cos[-Pi k]), {k, 0, 15}]
```

> `{0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1}`

we run

```
expr2 = FindSequenceFunction[{0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1,
         0, -1, 1, -1}, k] /. k -> k + 1 // Factor // Simplify // 
   Rationalize;
```

and we check

```
Chop[SetPrecision[
  Table[-5 Floor[1/5 (k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 4 k^4)] + k + 4 k^2 + k^3 + 
     4 k^4, {k, 0, 15}] - 
   Table[(1/2 ((-1)^k - 1)) - (-1 + Cos[-Pi k]) + expr2, {k, 0, 
     15}] , $MachinePrecision]]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: Thanks @ Kcr but I do not explain it well myself the above expressio it is to complicate to handle ,I need to simplify as combination of (-1)^n or cos( (pI/2 )n) or similar

Comment: @Charlessilva Yes, I just saw the updated version. Thanks for that. I think I have something but it's pretty complicated and ugly. Let me check it and I will update.

Comment: @Charlessilva I wrote the approach that came in mind and produced a result. I added as much details as I could. Please have a look and let me know :)

Comment: @ Kcr thanks works , but i want to find a way to automatize the process for other foemulas as above more complicate if it is possible of course

Comment: @Charlessilva it's nto clear to me what you mean when you say "other formulae". I think that the whole idea pretty much depends on each individual function. Do you mean different constants or something like that? Could you perhaps update the OP?